# Short story about a wizard and a child

Tags: story-identification, wizards, dreams

I believe I read this story in a fantasy anthology in the early nineties.  It was about a child who is the only other human being in a tiny world created by a wizard who is all-powerful within their reality.  He has created and destroyed a number of different things to amuse himself, but without much success.  It seems somehow that the child is different, and that he has some powers of his own.  At the end of the story, the wizard decides to uncreate the child, only to realize that the child actually created him instead of the other way around.

The overall concept is quite similar to the [Borges story referenced in this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53665/short-story-about-a-magician-who-is-in-a-dream-within-a-dream), but it is not the same story.  This one is considerably longer, more recent, and presumably first published in English.

I read this in the mid 90's and I think it may have appeared either in Isaac Asimov's magazine, or the Magazine of Science Fiction and Fantasy, or in one of the Asimov presents fantasy anthologies, but I haven't been able to locate it in any of those places.

Answer (score 2):

Man, that REALLY sounds like the Circular Ruins.  But you say it isn't, so... is it possibly [Oab](http://www.stephenmorrissey.ca/articles_reviews/SM_Oab.html) by Robert Zend?

It also reminds me of something by Italo Calvino, maybe in [Cosmocomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmicomics)

Comment: It's neither of these, but both sound right up my alley, I'll have to check them out.

Comment: Although these are not correct, I awarded the bounty to you because these sound like good suggestions for someone interested in the themes of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading a short story like that: "[The Sorceror Evoragdou](http://books.google.com/books?id=GpFEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=The%20Sorcerer%20Evoragdou&source=bl&ots=X5Sm_-JRi7&sig=lzRZUbhfjPwITD7vZoh2bLkhawA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r78qVKnCHo2gyATwroHoAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw)" .

Comment: I was able to find this one on Google.  It's not the one I'm looking for, although it does have similar themes.  It was well worth the read, so thanks for the tip.